# Si può usare l'avverbio "possibilmente" nel senso di "è possibile che ..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adverbs

Ho letto alcune frasi contenenti l'avverbio "possibilmente", ma in tali frasi questo avverbio aveva il significato di "se è possibile". Ad esempio:

> *Possibilmente prenota una camera a tre letti.*
>
> *Telefonami possibilmente.*

Vorrei sapere se questo avverbio si usa anche col significato di "è possibile che ...". Per esempio, posso scrivere "quest'uomo sembra molto preoccupato, possibilmente abbia dei problemi nel lavoro" nel senso di "è possibile che abbia dei problemi nel lavoro"?

Comment: _possibilmente_ è un "false friend" di _possibly_

Comment: Se la risposta qui sotto è corretta, è anche un "false friend" dell'avverbio spagnolo "posiblemente" e dell'avverbio catalano "possiblement".

Comment: Vorrei far notare che l'uso qui riportato di "possibilmente" è molto comune in Sicilia, dove l'avverbio si utilizza spesso come sostituto di "è possibile che", cosa errata in Italiano standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il significato di “possibilmente” è proprio “se possibile”. Nel vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/possibile/), alla fine della voce “possibile”, l'avverbio è definito ed esemplificato con

> Avv. **possibilménte**, potendo, se è possibile: *possibilmente, ti telefonerò domani; bisogna presentarsi possibilmente in abito da sera*.

L'avverbio invece *non* si usa col senso di “è possibile che”.
Il tuo esempio quindi non va molto bene perché lì intendi «*è possibile* che abbia dei problemi» (e comunque l'avverbio non sostituisce una proposizione principale, e quindi l'evento possibile non andrebbe al congiuntivo).

Nel senso che dici si potrebbero usare “forse”, “chissà se”, “magari” (tutti con l'indicativo).

Comment: anche "probabilmente" in alcuni casi va bene (lo si usa quando si propende per il si, non quando si è completamente in dubbio)

Answer (score 2):

La frase

> Possibilmente, ti telefonerò domani

non è utilizzata normalmente.

Di solito si ricorre a perifrasi del tipo:

> Nei limiti del possibile, ti telefonerò domani
>
> Se riesco, ti telefono domani

eccetera.

Invece è corretta una frase del tipo

> Ti telefono domani, *possibilmente entro le cinque*.

(nella lingua colloquiale si può omettere tranquillamente il futuro, ci si intende ugualmente).

*Possibilmente* è quindi legato a una ulteriore specificazione: *possibilmente entro le cinque del pomeriggio*.

A volte, *possibilmente* è utilizzato con una certa vena di sarcasmo e di ironia.

Un insegnante potrebbe ad esempio chiedere ad un alunno ritardatario e che si presenta a scuola sempre senza libri:

> Domani vieni a scuola con i libri e, possibilmente, in orario.

In questo caso, il *possibilmente* è utilizzato, appunto, con una sottile ironia. È infatti necessario che l'alunno si presenti a scuola puntuale e con tutti i libri.

Comment: "quest'uomo sembra molto preoccupato, possibilmente abbia dei problemi nel lavoro"  Questa frase non è corretta. in questo caso la seconda versione è quella giusta: è possibile che abbia dei problemi nel (di) lavoro.